# Android: ListFragment display blank space

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a `ListView` (inside a `ListFragment`) loading data with the help of a `LoaderManager`, to which I attach a `headerView` and a `footerView`. **My problem is that after doing that, it is displaying a lot of blank space (like almost an entire screen) after the footer is displayed.**
Some code from my ListFragment:

```
public class NewsDetailsFragment extends ListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(Const.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mId = getArguments().getLong(Const.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(NEWS_DETAILS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(COMMENTS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCommentsAdapter = new CommentsListAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_news_details_comments,
            container, false);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mHeaderView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.header, getListView(), false);
    mFooterView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.footer, getListView(), false);

    setUI();
    setAction();
    if (mHeaderView != null) {
        getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView);
    }
    if (mFooterView != null) {
        getListView().addFooterView(mFooterView);
    }
    setListAdapter(mCommentsAdapter);

}
```

Obviously, this is not the entire code from my ListFragment class, but the other stuff is mostly related to how the data is being manipulated (`Loader Callbacks` and others). If there is a need to add full code in order to be able to get the correct answer, I will add it on demand.

As for a general idea of how the screen should look like, the header displays some data about the article (which contains a bunch of `TextViews`, `ImageViews` and a `Webview`), the `ListView` displays comments on this article (if there are any), and the footer displays a form with writing a comment.

LE: This is how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot1]

LE2: This screenshot shows how headerView and footerView are limited.
headerView ends at "0 comments on this post:" and after that comes the footerView. In between these two, should be displayed the list of comments (if there are any)

[image: Screenshot2]

LE3: To make myself even more clear: I will display the wrong (red), and right (green) way it should be displayed.
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: @greenapps My bad, I copy pasted it wrong. Now it's been edited.

Comment: So the header is on top of the screen and the footer is on bottom of the screen? And there are not enough items to fill the screen?

Comment: what is the height of the frame where you are adding this fragment

Comment: @greenaps I reedited the question with a screenshot. The space is even larger, but I wanted to show that it comes after the footer.

Comment: @Pr38y it is match_parent on both dimensions and it comes after a small layout from the Activity.

Comment: So "Details" is the headerview and "Submit comment" is the footerview? I see no listview items with a bunch of textviews and so.

Comment: So do you want the footer to be on bottom of screen? Then why not tell so?

Comment: @greenapps the submitting form from the Screenshot comes from the footerView. My problem is why there is that empty space that comes after it?! The screen should 'end' its scrolling at the Submit Comment button.

Comment: Please asnwer all questions and comment on remarks. Repeat: How many items in the list? Not enough to fill a whole screen? And i see no items.

Comment: @greenapps Let me be more clear about the Screenshot. The bar on top with: back / Details / share comes from the Activity layout and has nothing to do with the ListFragment. Basicly the Activity holding this fragment is like this: a LinearLayout holding the top bar and the fragment itself. So the ListFragment  layout starts after the bar on top of the screen. I only displayed a part of the footer and the empty space that comes after it. Displaying all the list in screenshots would take like 5-6 pictures (because the header is very long).

Comment: @greenapps As for how many rows are there in the ListView that comes from the ListFragment, currently there are none (besides the HeaderView and the FooterView).

Comment: And what is the header view? The one with "Comment (required)" ?

Comment: @greenapps No, that is the footerView. The headerView is not displayed in the Screenshot, because it is too high in the ListView. I will reedit the post with a new Screenshot to explain the limit of headerView and footerView shortly.

Comment: Amazing that it took so long to get some relevant information. But now i do not understand your problem anymore: `it is displaying a lot of blank space (like almost an entire screen) after the footer is displayed.`.

Comment: @greenapps I'm sorry I'm not giving you the details you wanted. I can't express myself in another way that I already did. As I already said, first screenshot shows a lost of space under the "Submit Comment" button, that should not exist / appear. The scrolling should end at "Submit Comment" button, and not go anywhere after that. I will post another screenshot with the right way of how the fragment should end its scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had this background on footerView (the same of the ListView), just to test if everything looked fine, with textColor and stuff, and I forgot to remove it afterwards. Then it took its height, which was larger than the form in the footer, thus creating the empty space. Sry to have bothered your eyes with such stupidity.